# MongoDB aggregate/find consolidate array into seperate named elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document which contains an array of documents and I have the requirement to consolidate these into 1 flat document with names according to the array record number.

e.g.

```
{
'Name': 'Barry'
'Cars': [{
           'Model': 'Clio'
           'Reg':'WY99 XFT'
         }
         {
           'Model': 'Punto'
           'Reg': 'XX01 SDF'
         }]
}
```

to

```
{
'Name': 'Barry'
'Reg1': 'WY99 XFT'
'Reg2': 'XX01 SDF'
}
```

Is this even possible using the Mongoshell and aggregate functions?
I have tried variations of $unwind/$group but i cant seem to get the element number.
The JSON can have N number of Cars.

Comment: No this is not even practical. I don't say "impossible" but seriously you cannot "name keys" in the aggregation framework, and nor should you be doing so. You can `$map` to just extract the `Reg` values as an "array". But unless you are really dealing with "big data" then you should be doing this in "client" code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can basically do this using [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "Name": 1,
        "Regs": { 
            "$map": {
                "input": "$Cars",
                "as": "car",
                "in": "$$car.Reg"
             }
        }
    }}
])
```

Which will produce:

```
{
    "Name": "Barry",
    "Regs": [
        "WY99 XFT",
        "XX01 SDF"
    ]
}
```

Which is somthing you "can" do with the aggregation framework operators.

But it is not possible to give "arbitrary names" to "keys" in the output as you suggest.

So I would suggest sticking to what is possible, or otherwise doing what you want in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try create a new object by iterating the the collection's **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** cursor using the **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** method where you convert the `Cars` array into an object that you can add to the flattened object. The conversion can be made possible through the use of JavaScript native methods like **[`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)** and **[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**. The following mongo shell operation demonstrates this concept:

```
var flattened = [];

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var newRegObject = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc.Cars).reduce(function(o, v, i) {
        if (i < doc.Cars.length) o["Reg" + i] = doc.Cars[i].Reg;
        return o;
    }, {});
    newRegObject["Name"] = doc.Name;
    flattened.push(newRegObject);
})


printjson(flattened);
```

Comment: What part of the question asked about altertering the documents in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

1. > db.so.aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":0,"Name":1,"Reg1":"$Cars.Reg"}}])
   >   **will Produce** 
   >   { "Name" : "Barry", "Reg1" : [ "WY99 XFT", "XX01 SDF" ] }
2. > db.so.aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":0,"Name":1,"Reg1":"$Cars.Reg"}},{"$unwind"
   >   :"$Reg1"}])
   >   **Will Produce** 
   >   { "Name" : "Barry", "Reg1" : "WY99 XFT" }
   >   { "Name" : "Barry", "Reg1" : "XX01 SDF" }